# Um único form com vários panels ou forms MDI. Qual opção é mais eficiente quanto ao rendimento do programa?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, mdi

Sou iniciante em C#. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples, que possui várias janelas. Dependendo do que for necessário fazer no programa, o usuário precisa abrir várias janelas para chegar na página necessária. Eu gostaria de torná-lo mais leve e mais usual. Vi que uma das formas que poderia fazer isso é usando vários *panels* e botões laterais ou superiores (mais ou menos como funciona o CCleanner). Ou então, criar formulários filhos (MDI).

Gostaria de saber se uma das duas opções pode deixar o programa muito pesado, se alguma delas é mais eficaz que a outra, ou se o resultado quanto ao rendimento do programa será o mesmo para ambas.

Também vi que é possível usar o TabControl. Mas pelo que pesquisei não é possível personalizar as cores da moldura dele. Isso procede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularmente prefiro a abordagem de formulários filho por ser mais natural ao Windows Forms e você pode montar um menu bem apresentável com ícones no topo do formulário pai apenas usando os controles padrão.

Quanto ao rendimento da aplicação em relação as duas opções que você passou a não ser que você faça algo muito estranho com os Panels não vai haver diferença notável.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, user3111559! Abs

Answer (score 1):

De uma olhada na ferramenta ToolStrip, com ele você consegue deixar parecido com a interface do CCleaner que você mencionou. Da pra formatar ele de várias maneiras e deixar como você precisar.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Otávio! Só uma dúvida: pelo que percebi, para fazer uma interface parecida com a do CCleanner usando o ToolStrip, eu devo também usar vários painéis e trazê-los para frente conforme cada botão for clicado. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Da pra fazer assim mesmo, com os painéis, só ir modificando ao seu gosto dai.

Comment: Um outro modo de fazer isso é usando a propriedade Mdi dos forms. Não é complicado e use este link como referencia. [link]http://www.macoratti.net/09/08/c_mdi1.htm